# Microsoft AZURE SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm new to microsoft Azure. I Had a Production Database .I am facing few issues

**for Eg:** XYZ Which will reference from 2 Other Databases.while Creating BACPAC file I'm Getting Error reference is not Allowed

How can I Overcome with The Issue.your Help will Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAZURE is database  as a service,so you are actually working with only database  and it is not connected to any other database,but all the databases are grouped under one logical server for administrative purpose

In your case, you will have to remove all the references from other servers or other databases..

Few more options..

1.You can use SQLSERVER in a VM
2.you can use [elastic query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview)

There is one more new service called SQLAZURE managed instance which will be in public preview during this years Microsoft Ignite.This service has all the capabilties of SQLAZURE(Like automatic backups,HA..) and also all the features of an OnPremise server like SQLAGENT,linked servers,clr...

To start with elastci query,below is one easy place to start
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4550/sql-azure-cross-database-querying/

Comment: Thanks @TheGameIswar it help me out.